# pyspark xpath extract child node

Tags: xml, xpath, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created the below sample XML and I am trying to extract the chaild node values using xpath

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
                             <ns1:visitors> <ns1:visit name="loy"> \
                                 <ns1:visitor id="9615" > 123 </ns1:visitor> \
                                 <ns1:visitor id="9616" > Dr George </ns1:visitor> \
                                 <ns1:visitor id="9617" > India </ns1:visitor> \
                                </ns1:visit><ns1:visit name="loy1"> \
                                 <ns1:visitor id="9610" > 123 </ns1:visitor> \
                                 <ns1:visitor id="9611" > Dr George </ns1:visitor> \
                                 <ns1:visitor id="9612" > India </ns1:visitor> \
                                </ns1:visit></ns1:visitors>']], ['visitors'])
```

My goal is : for name="loy" extract value corresponding to id 9616
i.e my output should be Dr George

I tried below code

```
df=df.selectExpr(
    "xpath(visitors, './visitors/visit[@name = loy]/visitor[@id = 9611]/text()') id"
)
```

but it is giving output as []

Please could someone help

Answer (score 0):

The XML in your data frame is not well-formed, because it contains elements whose names start with a namespace prefix (`ns1`), but the prefix is not bound to a namespace URI (i.e. you are missing the namespace declaration which would make that namespace prefix meaningful).

Try removing the namespace prefix from the elements' names.